# REST Assured: compare field to a long value

Tags: rest-assured

Consider this line:

`response.body("path.to.some.long",is(getExpectedResult())`

What I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path path.to.some.long doesn't match.
Expected: is <1500L>
  Actual: 1500
```

Does that mean REST assured compares a String to a Long? This is very limiting.

How can I tell REST assured to compare it as a long value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to go the traditional way

```
    long value = response.jsonPath().getLong("path.to.some.long");
    assertThat(value, is(1500L));
```

Comment: TBH, it's a bummer since: (1) it requires an extra line of code. (2) it requires me to use my own assertion library, but I'm sure the creators of the library have their own reasoning